# UWP - prevent app from activating or taking focus

Tags: windows, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app that is designed to use **InputInjector** to send keyboard input to *another* application (let's say Chrome).  The InputInjector is invoked when a PointerPressed event is handled within the app.  I'm basically trying to recreate the functionality of the OSK with a custom UWP app.

The issue I'm running into is, when the user interacts with my app (ie via touch), the focus is pulled away from the app I want to send keyboard input to (which had the focus originally), which prevents the key strokes from going to the right application.

My question is, is there a property or value I can set on the application, window, or control, that prevents my app from taking focus (or being activated?) when the user interacts with it?

Currently my workaround is to inject a mouse-down event first, which effectively clicks on the target app to bring it back to the front, before sending the keyboard input.

Here's a snippet:

```
_input = InputInjector.TryCreate();
List<InjectedInputMouseInfo> mouseInfo = new List<InjectedInputMouseInfo>
                {
                    new InjectedInputMouseInfo
                    {
                        MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftDown
                    }
                };
                _input.InjectMouseInput(mouseInfo);
                mouseInfo[0].MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftUp;
                _input.InjectMouseInput(mouseInfo);


                // Try inserting keyboard input
                Debug.WriteLine("Grid: Inserting Keyboard Info");
                List<InjectedInputKeyboardInfo> keyboardInfo =
                    new List<InjectedInputKeyboardInfo>
                    {
                        new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
                        {
                            VirtualKey = (ushort)Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control
                        },
                        new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
                        {
                            VirtualKey = (ushort)Windows.System.VirtualKey.S
                        }
                    };
                // Press keys
                _input.InjectKeyboardInput(keyboardInfo);

                // Raise keys
                keyboardInfo[0].KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
                keyboardInfo[1].KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
                _input.InjectKeyboardInput(keyboardInfo);
```

Comment: In UWP, we can't prevent the window from getting focus. So currently, you still need to use your workaround.

Comment: Unfortunate, but thanks for the clarification @Faywang-MSFT